# Connecting to websphere MQ using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, websphere, ibm-mq

I need to push a message to MQ from ruby code. The only gem I see is WMQ and I don't think that works on OSX systems (mine is a remote MQ)

What are options I have? I can't find any details on this online

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to use Java on Mac OS X rather than Ruby.  But if you want to stick with Ruby then your only option is to use [MQ Light](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/ibm-mq-light-downloads/) to communicate with an MQ Server via AMQP protocol.

Note: AMQP protocol was introduced in MQ v8.0.0.4.